# Eclipse J2EE preview server fails to find deployed pages

Tags: java, eclipse, webserver

I have a dynamic web project named `Report` that utilizes the default generation strategy employed by Eclipse.  I have added a page `hello.jsp` underneath the `WEB-INF` directory and have deployed the the J2EE preview server.  When the page launches in my browser I am directed to the following URL:
`http://localhost:8080/Report`

this page has two hyperlinks:

`META-INF`
`WEB-INF`

both with sizes of zero (0) bytes.  My question is why am I unable to access `/Report/hello.jsp`?  It results in a not found similarly `/Report/WEB-INF/hello.jsp` also results in a not found exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files in `/WEB-INF` and `/META-INF` folders are intented for MVC view files, template files, include files, tag files, configuration files, etc, not for public web resources which are intented to be directly accessed by URL.

Put your `hello.jsp` outside `/WEB-INF` folder and access it by `/Report/hello.jsp` instead.

```
WebContent
 |-- META-INF
 |-- WEB-INF
 |    `-- web.xml
 `-- hello.jsp
```

If you really need to have your JSP in `/WEB-INF` folder (in order to act as a MVC view), then you need to create a front controller servlet which serves it up by `RequestDispatcher#forward()`. See [also our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) for a kickoff example.

Comment: Most helpful as always once I get it implemented I will accept.